# Run CLI as local npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I just created and published an npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/reduxboilergen

This is supposed to run as cli , now when I install and run the package as

```
npm i -g reduxboilergen
```

This is fine and works as expected.
But when i try to install as

```
npm i -S reduxboilergen
```

This is not installed as expected as I don't see it in the bin package

```
npm bin
```

Also running the bin command boilredux does not work.
Any ideas how can I run this CLI installing as a local node module instead of global?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `-S` switch is supposed to do? I couldn't find any reference to it.

Comment: I think that to run locally installed package you need to point to the executable file. You could use `npm run bin` if you add to a scripts property in package.json `"bin": "build\\index.js"`

Comment: @Molda: it's a shorthand for `npm install --save`. Correspondingly, `npm i -D` is also a shorthand for `npm install --save-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by , the bin path was pointing as so:

```
  "bin": {
    "boilredux": "build\\index.js"
  },
```

which worked fine in windows but not in linux
Chnaged it to

```
  "bin": {
    "boilredux": "build/index.js"
  },
```

and now the file is pointing in npm bin directory.